# Tailwind not applying styles to pages in Nextjs but applies to index page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Brand new to Tailwind and Nextjs, but have made some projects in the past with create-react-app. I'm struggling to figure out why Tailwind is not applying styles to my pages, but applies styles to my index page (`page.tsx`). Directly importing Tailwind to `test.tsx` applies the styles but I would rather have Tailwind be applied to everything with just the single import in `layout.tsx`.

globals.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

layout.tsx:

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
 
import './globals.css'
 
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>{children}</body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

Folder Structure (Only showing relevant files and folders):

```
.
├── app
│   ├── globals.css
│   └── layout.tsx
│   └── page.tsx
├── pages
│   └── test.tsx
├── tailwind.config.js
└── package.json
```

Comment: I think I may have fixed this after playing with the tailwind.config.js file. All I did was delete and re-pasted the content array and suddenly the test.tsx page was rendering the Tailwind classes. I made no changes to the file. Maybe the Tailwind config file somehow needed a refresh?

Comment: Sometimes, deleting and re-pasting the file can help to clear any errors or inconsistencies.

Comment: I see. I'm assuming that is some Nextjs logic working behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes, Next.js has some logic to optimize your project for production, such as code splitting, minification, etc. It also uses webpack to bundle your assets and modules. Sometimes, these processes can cause some issues with your styles or scripts, especially if you are using external libraries or frameworks like Tailwind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything was configured correctly. I had to somehow refresh my `tailwind.config.js` file to apply the Tailwind classes to `test.tsx`. See Victor L's comments for more detail.

Comment: Facing the same issue and above solutions are not working for me

Answer (score 1):

It is not applying styles to pages route because it was only imported in app/layout and works only for routes in app directory.

To apply for routes in pages as well, you need to import **globals.css** in the routes on /pages.

`import "@/styles/globals.css";`